AWS Cloudwatch Log Insight- selecting only certain fields from parsed message
I have the following log table, which parses the PostgreSQL log for slow queries and works fine
fields @timestamp as QueryTimePT
| filter @message like "LOG:  duration"
| parse @message "* UTC:*(*):*[*]:LOG:  duration: * ms *" as QueryTimeUTC, IP, RemotePort, User, PID, DurationMS, Query
| fields abs(DurationMS) / 60000 as DurationMinutes
| sort QueryTimePT desc

However, I really only want a few columns: QueryTimePT, User, Query, DurationMinutes. I merely assign the others because they are taken from the log file, it made parsing via glob easier.
Is there a way to finally only select some subset here?

is it about simplifying parse pattern or it is enough just to reduce number of columns in the output? If latter then use | display QueryTimePT, User, Query, DurationMinutes

Perfect, would mark as best answer if you had not left it as a comment. Thanks!
